# How to know the connected WiFi is Walled Gardened (Captive Portal)?

Tags: android, networking, captivenetwork

I know there is way to find out whether a WiFi network is a captive portal by checking the response of something like `"http://clients3.google.com/generate_204"`.

But my question is somewhat different. We all know that on Android when we connect to a WiFi network the connection cycle goes through a number of state mentioned in the class [NetworkInfo.DetailedState](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/NetworkInfo.DetailedState.html), like `AUTHENTICATING`, `OBTAINING_IPADDR`, `VERIFYING_POOR_LINK` etc. Also, one of the states is `CAPTIVE_PORTAL_CHECK` and android system check whether the network which is being connected is captive or not. For this Android uses the [CaptivePortalTracker#isCaptivePortal(InetAddress server)](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.4.4_r1/android/net/CaptivePortalTracker.java#CaptivePortalTracker.isCaptivePortal%28java.net.InetAddress%29) which results in a `boolean`. So we are certain that Android knows whether the connection is restricted (captive) or not

So, my question is **does Android system gives some callback or some state by which we can get to know the Network is captive portal without checking it manually?** Since Android system have already checked the network for captive portal, do we need to do the same thing again?

P.S. I'm only targeting API 19 (KitKat 4.4.2).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get the networkcapabilities from the network and check if it has the `NET_CAPABILITY_CAPTIVE_PORTAL` :

**API 23**

```
ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
Network activeNetwork=connectivityManager.getActiveNetwork();
NetworkCapabilities networkCapabilities=connectivityManager.getNetworkCapabilities(activeNetwork);
if(networkCapabilities.hasCapability(NetworkCapabilities.NET_CAPABILITY_CAPTIVE_PORTAL)){
        //DO SOMETHING
}
```

http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/net/NetworkCapabilities.html

NetworkCapabilities was introduced in API 21, so you can do this for

**API >= 21**

```
ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
Network[] activeNetworks=connectivityManager.getAllNetworks();
for(Network network:activeNetworks){
    if(connectivityManager.getNetworkInfo(network).isConnected()){
        NetworkCapabilities networkCapabilities=connectivityManager.getNetworkCapabilities(network);
        if(networkCapabilities.hasCapability(NetworkCapabilities.NET_CAPABILITY_CAPTIVE_PORTAL)){
           //DO SOMETHING
        }
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @isma3l, will check this and revert back with one more thanks :-)

Comment: Hi @isma3l, this require API 23 (Marshmallow) to work. Do we have anything like this for previous versions?

Comment: Thanks isma3l, good to know that NetworkCapabilities were introduced in API 121. But I'm specifically targeting API 19. So, how can this be employed in API 19?

Comment: Anything for APIs less than 21?

Answer (score 0):

Might be late to the party. But If the documentations hold correct then there is a way to detect captive portal from connectivityManager. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/NetworkInfo.DetailedState.html#CAPTIVE_PORTAL_CHECK

```
ConnectivityManager connectivityManager
                = (ConnectivityManager)context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
NetworkInfo activeNetworkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
NetworkInfo.DetailedState detailedState = activeNetworkInfo.getDetailedState();
return detailedState == NetworkInfo.DetailedState.CAPTIVE_PORTAL_CHECK;
```

PS: This is deprecated in API 29